# Jenkins weather results, vs. Matlab, vs. powershell

Tags: matlab, powershell, jenkins

I have a pws script running from Jenkins, where it triggers matlab to do perform a test. If the test finished execution it may pass/fail. This info I would like to capture and use to influence the sunny/clouds of the Jenkins weather/results
dashboard.

Can someone tell me, based on what information in the pws script, Jenkins decides to put a sun or clouds in the overview?

Thanx.

Comment: depending on the number of recent job failures

Comment: Which variable or which setting in Jenkins collect/has this info to put a sun/clouds? thnx

Answer (score 0):

The 'weather' indicates the health status of the project:

- No. of failures during the last 5 of builds.
- Test coverage data
- Other metrics that plugins might supply

The 'balls' indicate the status of the last build.

[image: Typical Jenkins view]

So to have 'nice weather', your last 5 builds need to succeed and there must be no other negative metric like having only little code coverage.

The only thing your `pws` script influences is the build status. Whether the build succeeds or fails is determined by the exit status of the last non-failing command. If it is 0 (normal) then it succeeds, otherwise it fails.